# ZeroPadding2D Dimension

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

According to MobileNet Ver2. API provided by Keras, we observe output dimension of width and height of ZeroPadding2D increases only by 1 as the picture shown below. [image]

However, zero-padding increases the output dimension by 2 times of zero-padding integer for CNN calculation mechanism. The experiment shown below by ZeroPadding2D() also proves the idea. Thus, how can dimension output of ZeroPadding2D() by MobileNetV2 API increase only by 1 since padding=0.5 is not legal for setting, too?

```py
input_shape=(224,224,3)
x_in = Input(input_shape)
x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1,0), data_format='channels_last')(x_in)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)
test_model = Model(inputs=x_in, outputs=x)
test_model.summary()
```

[image]

Comment: Please [use text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) instead of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ZeroPadding2D`, `padding` can be int, or tuple of 2 ints, or tuple of 2 tuples of 2 ints. According to the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/):

- If int: the same symmetric padding is applied to height and width.
- If tuple of 2 ints: interpreted as two different symmetric padding values for height and width: `(symmetric_height_pad, symmetric_width_pad)`.
- If tuple of 2 tuples of 2 ints: interpreted as  `((top_pad, bottom_pad), (left_pad, right_pad))`.

MobileNet uses a padding of `((0, 1), (0, 1))` (see the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/mobilenet.py)). As a result, the width and height are increased by 1 (`top_pad=0, bottom_pad=1, left_pad=0, right_pad=1`).

Comment: Hello Soroush, thanks so much for the reply! I learn from it!